# ITextSharp PDFTemplate FormFlattening removes filled data

Tags: c#, itext

I am porting an existing app from Java to C#.  The original app used the IText library to fill PDF form templates and save them as new PDF's.  My C# code (example) below:

```
string templateFilename = @"C:\Templates\test.pdf"; 
string outputFilename = @"C:\Output\demo.pdf";

using (var existingFileStream = new FileStream(templateFilename, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (var newFileStream = new FileStream(outputFilename, FileMode.Create))
    {
        var pdfReader = new PdfReader(existingFileStream);
        var stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, newFileStream);

        var form = stamper.AcroFields;
        var fieldKeys = form.Fields.Keys;

        foreach (string fieldKey in fieldKeys)
        {
            form.SetField(fieldKey, "REPLACED!");
        }

        stamper.FormFlattening = true;
        stamper.Close();
        pdfReader.Close();
    }
}
```

All works well only if I ommit the

```
stamper.FormFlattening = true;
```

line, but then the forms are visible as...forms.
When I add the this line, any values set to the form fields are lost, resulting in a blank form.  I would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: I'm using 5.4.4.0 (latest from SourceForge if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Maybe you're experiencing a problem similar to this problem: http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Blank-fields-when-forms-are-159987.S.269853429?qid=6588ea59-f2e7-45e2-aa84-bff2dcf38718&trk=groups_most_popular-0-b-ttl&goback=.gmp_159987 Maybe not.

Comment: In any case: if you can't reproduce the problem with iText, only with iTextSharp, you'll have to ask a C# developer. Most of the C# iTextSharp people can only be reached through the ticketing system for paying customers.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder if it's not the PDF form I'm using - created using OpenOffice.  But then again, working fine with IText, but just not ITextSharp.  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Maybe the NeedAppearances flag was set incorrectly. There was a change in this area between iText 5.4.3 and 5.4.4. Are you using 5.4.3 in Java and 5.4.4 in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved the issue by using a previous version of ITextSharp (5.4.3).  Not sure what the cause is though...

Comment: This doesn't help us, does it? We'd like to debug iText, but we can't if you don't give us more info...

Comment: We'd like to know if this problem also exists in iText 5.4.4 (the Java version). We'd also like to receive a form that we can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: IText version used in Java app: 2.1.7 (old).  ITextSharp version causing issue: 5.4.4. PDF Forms were create using OpenOffice.

I therefore cannot comment at the moment whether this would be the same issue in IText 5.4.4.  Where can I send the form to?

Comment: Thanks. I'll make an internal ticket about this myself.

Answer (score 22):

Most likely you can resolve this when using iTextSharp 5.4.4 (or later) by forcing iTextSharp to generate appearances for the form fields.  In your example code:

```
var form = stamper.AcroFields;
form.GenerateAppearances = true;
```

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie: This worked for me too. I was following every example I could find and it still wasn't working, thought I was going mad! Does anyone have any idea what the problem is and why this solution works?

Comment: it works for itextpdf in java also, with
`AcroFields form = pdfStamper.getAcroFields();`
`form.setGenerateAppearances(true);`

Comment: This worked for me, just make sure you set GenerateAppearances before setting the fields and FormFlattening afterwards.

Comment: Could someone post a full solution instead of 2 lines please? I'm not sure about the order where this 2 lines supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution for this for any och the newer iTextSharp.
The way we do it was:
1- Create a copy of the pdf temmplate.
2- populate the copy with data.
3- FormFlatten = true and setFullCompression
4- Combine some of the PDFs to a new document.
5- Move the new combined document and then remove the temp.

This way we got the issue with removed input and if we skipped the "formflatten" it looked ok.

However when we moved the "FormFlatten = true" from step 3 and added it as a seperate step after the moving etc was complete, it worked perfectly.

Hope I explained somewhat ok :)

Answer (score -2):

In your PDF File, change the property to **Visible**, the Default value is **Visible but not printable**.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.