# Itext Sharp Merge Pdfs with acrofields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext

I'm using itext sharp to fill my form fields on my template with values.

I created the template using [pdfescape.com](http://www.pdfescape.com/)

Here is my code that I use to place the values in the pdf template.

```
 private static byte[] GeneratePdf(Dictionary<String, String> formKeys, String pdfPath)
    {
        var templatePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(pdfPath);
        var reader = new PdfReader(templatePath);
        var outStream = new MemoryStream();
        var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outStream);

        var form = stamper.AcroFields;
        var fieldKeys = form.Fields.Keys;

        // "Flatten" the form so it wont be editable/usable anymore  
      //  stamper.FormFlattening = true;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> pair in formKeys)
        {
            if (fieldKeys.Any(f => f == pair.Key))
            {
                form.SetField(pair.Key, pair.Value);
                form.SetFieldProperty(pair.Key, "setfflags", PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY, null);
            }
        }
        stamper.Close();
        reader.Close();

        return outStream.ToArray();
    }
```

I first used the stamper.FormFlattening = true, but then the values weren't visible. So Instead of using the form flattening I just set the values as ready only and everything works fine.

Now I want to merge multiple of these pdf files using the [the pdf merger by smart-soft](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28283/Simple-NET-PDF-Merger)

Once the merging is complete the values aren't visible. When I highlight over the form it highlights all the text, but I can't read it.I did research on this and read that the fields need to be flattened.

Here is an image of how it looks on the pdf when I highlight everything:
[image: Image of pdf highlighted Text]

I don't know why my fields aren't visible when they are flattened, even if I don't use the merger. Is there something wrong with the code or the template? Alternatives will also be appreciated.

Btw my project is an asp-mvc project if that is relevant.

***EDIT***

I added the following code so that I first read the template, write the values to the form fields, close it, reopen it, flatten and then close it again as suggested by one of the comments. I just pass the result I get from the GeneratePdf function to this function:

```
private static byte[] flattenPdf(byte[] pdf)
    {
        var reader = new PdfReader(pdf);

        var outStream = new MemoryStream();
        var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outStream);

        stamper.FormFlattening = true;

        stamper.Close();
        reader.Close();

        return outStream.ToArray();
    }
```

I still get the same result

Comment: *Now I want to merge multiple of these pdf files using [the the pdf merger by smart-soft](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28283/Simple-NET-PDF-Merger)* - That code throws away all form elements. Better use iTextSharp merging samples by iText.

Comment: *I don't know why my fields aren't visible when they are flattened, even if I don't use the merger.* - do form filling and flattening in separate passes, i.e. first read, fill form elements, write, read again, flatten, write.

Comment: @mkl, I added my code to my question that I use to first write, close, reopen and the flatten.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem thanks to [this answer by rhens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19813756/1581026)

All I had to do is modify my GeneratePdf function by adding one line:

```
form.GenerateAppearances = true;
```

Here is the end result:

```
private static byte[] GeneratePdf(Dictionary<String, String> formKeys, String pdfPath)
    {
        var templatePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(pdfPath);
        var reader = new PdfReader(templatePath);
        var outStream = new MemoryStream();
        var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outStream);

        var form = stamper.AcroFields;
        form.GenerateAppearances = true; //Added this line, fixed my problem
        var fieldKeys = form.Fields.Keys;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> pair in formKeys)
        {
            if (fieldKeys.Any(f => f == pair.Key))
            {
                form.SetField(pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }
        }
        stamper.Close();
        reader.Close();

        return flattenPdf(outStream.ToArray());
    }
```

and the flattenPdf stays the same as in my question.

Comment: Ok. So it was one of those `/NeedAppearances true` files. Oh well.