# Setting AcroField text color in itextSharp

Tags: itext

I am using iTextSharp 5.5.3 i have a PDF with named fields i created with Adobe lifecycle I am able to fill the fields using iTextSharp but when i change the textcolor for a field it does not change. i really dont know why this is so. here is my code below

```
        form.SetField("name", "Michael Okpara");
        form.SetField("session", "2014/2015");
        form.SetField("term", "1st Term");

        form.SetFieldProperty("name", "textcolor", BaseColor.RED, null);
        form.RegenerateField("name");
```

Comment: It should really be prohibited to downvote without a comment.

Answer (score 3):

If your form is created using Adobe LifeCycle, then there are two options:

- **You have a pure XFA form.** XFA stands for the XML Forms Architecture and your PDF is nothing more than a container of an XML stream. There is hardly any PDF syntax in the document and there are no AcroForm fields. I don't think this is the case, because you are still able to fill out the fields (which wouldn't work if you had a pure XFA form).
- **You have a hybrid form.** In this case, the form is described twice inside the PDF file: once using an XML stream (XFA) and once using PDF syntax (AcroForm). iText will fill out the fields in both descriptions, but the XFA description gets preference when rendering the document. Changing the color of a field (or other properties) would require changing the XML and iText(Sharp) can not do that.

If I may make an educated guess, I would say that you have a hybrid form and that you are only changing the text color of the AcroForm field without changing the text color in the XFA field (which is really hard to achieve).

Please try adding this line:

```
form.RemoveXfa();
```

This will remove the XFA stream, resulting in a form that only keeps the AcroForm description.

I have written a small example named [RemoveXFA](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/RemoveXFA) using the form you shared to demonstrate this. This is the C#/iTextSharp version of that example:

```
public void ManipulatePdf(String src, String dest)
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create));
    AcroFields form = stamper.AcroFields;
    form.RemoveXfa();
    IDictionary<String, AcroFields.Item> fields = form.Fields;
    foreach (String name in fields.Keys)
    {
        if (name.IndexOf("Total") > 0)
            form.SetFieldProperty(name, "textcolor", BaseColor.RED, null);
        form.SetField(name, "X");
    }
    stamper.Close();
    reader.Close();
}
```

In this example, I remove the XFA stream and I look over all the remaining AcroFields. I change the textcolor of all the fields with the word "Total" in their name, and I fill out every field with an "X".

The result looks like this: [reportcard.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/reportcard.pdf)

[image]

All the fields show the letter "X", but the fields in the TOTAL column are written in red.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added form.RemoveXfa() and all the fields that were previously filled became empty. Now i went back to adobe life cycle, made another copy and saved it as 'Adobe Dynamic XML form' as against 'Adobe Static PDF Form' which i used earlier ran my program it ran without errors but when i try to open the resulting filled document i get this "Please wait... If this message is not eventually replaced by the proper contents of the document, your PDF viewer may not be able to display this type of document...." I have the latest Adobe XI

Comment: If you create a form as 'Adobe Dynamic XML form', then your form does not contain any AcroForm fields, hence you can not change the text color. You really need the 'Adobe Static PDF Form', but it worries me that the fields are not filled out. Can you share the PDF document?

Comment: Ok i really don't know how to share a file here can't seem to find any link for that can you direct me?

Comment: Shared https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ZNcswFqdOxVnlkRDdoUVRDdXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. your code is in JAVA I am doing same in C# (iTextSharp) and its still not working...

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've made a support ticket so that the people responsible for porting iText to C# can check what is wrong (either a porting error in your code, or a porting error in iTextSharp). It's a ticket with low priority, but as soon as I get a reply, I'll update this post.

Comment: Bruno's example has the same behavior in C#/iTextSharp. So if it does not work for you, you probably have a porting issue somewhere. I edited the answer to include the C# code, but it needs to be peer reviewed before it shows.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way, guess the problem was coming from using Adobe LC, so i switched to Open Office it all worked but when i flatten the form everything disappears. I found a solution to that here [ITextSharp PDFTemplate FormFlattening removes filled data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925311/itextsharp-pdftemplate-formflattening-removes-filled-data)

Thanks Mr Lowagie for your help