# iTextSharp doesn't work after update

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, itext

After updating iTextSharp with NuGet the PDF generation stopped working.

i updated from 4.1.2.0 to 5.5.4.0

My original code was

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{  
    var reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
    var stp = new PdfStamper(reader, stream);
    var writer = stp.Writer;
    var fieldsManager = stp.AcroFields;

    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in fieldsManager.Fields)
    {
        var strEntry = entry.Key.ToString();
        if (strEntry == "txtNoServicio") fieldsManager.SetField(strEntry, orden.NoServicio.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        if (strEntry == "txtFechaCreacionTicket") fieldsManager.SetField(strEntry, orden.FechaCreacionTicket.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        if (strEntry == "txtAgenteAsignado") fieldsManager.SetField(strEntry, orden.AgenteAsignado);
        ...
    }

    stp.FormFlattening = true;
    stp.Close();
    reader.Close();
    dataBytes = stream.GetBuffer();
}

return dataBytes;
```

After update I changed the foreach loop from

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in fieldsManager.Fields)
```

to

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, AcroFields.Item> entry in fieldsManager.Fields)
```

The method continues to return the PDF successfully but SetValues with SetField in PDF doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Debugging I see `fieldsManager.Fields` contain a property called Values and it contains a property called `IsReadOnly` which is set to `True`. Could it mean something?

Comment: Which versions did you upgrade from and to?

Comment: from 4.1.2.0 to 5.5.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have jumped from a version that was released in 2008 to a version that was released in 2014. There are **6 years** between these two versions.

[image: One does not simply...]

(Sorry, I couldn't resist creating a *Game of Thrones* meme ;-) )

Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the problem. Many people are filling out forms with iTextSharp 5.5.x without experiencing any problem.

What happens if you add the following line:

```
form.GenerateAppearances = true;
```

See [ITextSharp PDFTemplate FormFlattening removes filled data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925311/itextsharp-pdftemplate-formflattening-removes-filled-data)

If this fixes your problem, then your original form has a setting that prevents iTextSharp from generating the appearances. Old iTextSharp versions *ignored* this setting. More recent versions *respect* that setting.

Comment: thank you so much it work. Consider also before run my code it was updated how say the ebook the best itext questions on stackoverflow and changed my old code. i never expected it execute as such