# ITextSharp PDFTemplate FormFlattening removes radio buttons

Tags: vb.net, forms, pdf, radio-button, itext

I'm using vb.net with itextsharp to collect several PDF-files including forms. The collected files are merged to one whole ".pdf" file using the itextsharp `cb.AddTemplate-function`.

With [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925311/itextsharp-pdftemplate-formflattening-removes-filled-data) I've been able to "fix" text filled into pdf-form's text fields to the form by using:

```
stamper.FormFlattening = True
```

The problem is that the forms can have radio buttons too, which get lost when I'm using `cd.AddTemplate`, even though I used `stamper.FormFlattening = True`.

Is there a possibility to fix this?

Comment: Instead of using direct content (the `cb`) I'd recommend checking out this example for merging forms: http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/MergeForms

Comment: Beside merging the ".pdf" file page by page using cb.AddTemplate-function I do also rotate and scale single pages as fas as necessary. Thus I'd like to stay with my cb.AddTemplate-solution if there is an other possibility to fix forms.