# Change text of label in PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have problems with editing fields inside of an PDF document.

I created a simple invoice with OpenOffice and added some fields via the form creation tool. I exported it as PDF with forms after that.

One of the fields I want to change is named "{Firma}" and I want to fill this field with a string.

Below is a short example-code which doesnt seem to work, the field "{Firma}" in the output-file is still empty.

```
public static void ReplacePdfForm()
    {
        string fileNameExisting = @".\template\templaterechnung.pdf";
        string fileNameNew = @".\rechnung.pdf";

        using (var existingFileStream = new FileStream(fileNameExisting, FileMode.Open))
        using (var newFileStream = new FileStream(fileNameNew, FileMode.Create))
        {
            // Open existing PDF
            var pdfTemplate = new PdfReader(existingFileStream);

            // PdfStamper, (PDF to be changed)
            var pdfInvoice = new PdfStamper(pdfTemplate, newFileStream);

            AcroFields fields = pdfInvoice.AcroFields;

            // set form fields

            fields.SetField("{Firma}", "Test1");

            pdfInvoice.FormFlattening = true;
            pdfInvoice.FreeTextFlattening = true;
            pdfInvoice.Close();
            pdfTemplate.Close();
        }
    }
```

(I have some more fields which also don't change but I deleted them from code because they behave the same way.)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here's my PDF: http://www.file-upload.net/download-11071404/templaterechnung.pdf.html

EDIT2:

This is how I set the property in OpenOffice:
[image: OpenOffice TextField Property]

Comment: Why don't you want `Writer` to close the stream? Why are you using the word "label" instead of "field"? You can change the text of a field, you can't change the text of a label. That would explain why "it doesn't work." Unless you are just confusing your audience by saying "label" when you actually mean "field" (in that case: please don't expect your audience to provide an accurate answer). In any case, it would surprise me very much if you had a field named `{Firma}`. Why would you use curly braces in a field name? Why don't you share your PDF?

Comment: Also: did you follow the instructions of section 6.3.5 in [chapter 6 of my book](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/3/3c9ca46-76da-4de2-8972-b82efbe0bf88/samplechapter6.pdf) step by step? If not, you shouldn't use words like "doesn't work" because that would be blaming the tool instead of blaming the person using the tool incorrectly.

Comment: As you can tell from my book: it works for me (and it works for many other developers), so unless you share your PDF, we'll have to close this question as unclear what you're asking. You aren't providing sufficient data to allow anyone to give you any other answer than "it works for us."

Comment: Hello Bruno, thank you for your answer. I'm relatively new to C# and only work with it in my spare time so sorry for the information that I forgot to add. I'm going to post my pdf in a few minutes.

Comment: Which version of iTextSharp are you using? I'm asking this because you may be using a version that requires `fields.GenerateAppearances = true;` as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925311/itextsharp-pdftemplate-formflattening-removes-filled-data) (Open Office is using a wrong parameter in the form.)

Comment: I am using iTextSharp core 5.5.7
BTW: Sorry again for the missing information.
I'm not that often on stackoverflow so asking a precise answer is not a skill that I have yet ;-)

Comment: Does adding `fields.GenerateAppearances = true;` help?

Comment: Adding "fields.GenerateAppearances = true;" solved the problem.
Thanks to Bruno Lowagie for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a form with Open Office, Open Office adds a parameter to the PDF instructing software processing the PDF not to create any appearance streams, but to leave it up to the PDF viewer to create those appearances.

This works as long as the form remains interactive, but as soon as you flatten the form, no appearances are created at all.

You can work around this problem by adding the following line:

```
fields.GenerateAppearances = true;
```

This way, you force iTextSharp to generate the appearances.